# Basic deep linking not working with React Navigation and Redux

Tags: react-native, react-navigation, deep-linking

EDIT:
I am wondering if this issue is related to the fact that I have the redux store wrapping the appContainer. Is there another way I am supposed to handle deep linking when using Redux?

---

I cannot get my deep links to work. They open up the app but do not direct to any page. I have followed directions exactly as is listed here https://reactnavigation.org/docs/en/bottom-tab-navigator.html

I am not sure if it is because of the createSwitchNavigator. I can't figure out how to troubleshoot to figure this out either.

```
const AppSwitchNavigator = createSwitchNavigator({
  Open: { screen: AuthStackNavigator },
  Home: {
    screen: MainStackNavigator,
    path: ''
  }
})

const AppContainer = createAppContainer(AppSwitchNavigator)

const PREFIX = 'myApp://';

const App = () => {
  return (
    <Provider store={store}>
        <AppContainer
          uriPrefix={PREFIX}
        />
    </Provider>
  )
}
```

In MainStackNavigator I have this...

```
const MainStackNavigator = createStackNavigator(
  {
    MainTabNavigator: {
      screen: MainTabNavigator,
      path: ''
    },

    Contact: {
      screen: Contact,
      path: 'contact',
    },
    ...
```

But when i go to myApp://contact - it opens the app but doesn't go the contact screen, and of course, any of the screens in the TabNavigator don't get anywhere either.

Comment: did you solve it? I had this issue, no redux, but AppContainer wrapped in react contexts, and it turns out that had nothing to do with it. Having "remote debugging" enabled messes up the apps ability to handle urls. Disabling remote debugging made it work for me. If you don't have remote debugging enabled, you should make sure you have setup everything properly on the native side. To test this quickly, just comment out your app and make a very simple two route setup that doesn't use redux. You should do that so you know for sure that redux is causing the problem.